# How to move a point on a touch screen using esri map, dojo and javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point, dojo

I am new to map development. For touch screen devices, I need to add a point on an ESRI map and then move this point to other location on the map and get its coordinates.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is working and what is not working. Can you post the relevant code  with your comments.  Questions about coding that have the code attached are much more likely to be answered than those without.